# Generics - Extending the builder pattern on an object that is of a generic type

Tags: java, generics, builder

I have been attempting implement an extendable Builder pattern in Java that uses non-static inner classes for the builders. I have been able to achieve this, but ran into an issue that I do not understand. When I add a generic type to the enclosing class(the thing being built), the fluent interface is broken. That is, the type returned by the builder methods of the parent are no longer of the child type.

```
package inh;

public class Rabbit<T> {

public Rabbit(){}

private String rabbit;

public String getRabbit(){
    return rabbit;
}

public Rabbit(ParentBuilder b){
    rabbit = b.rabbit;
}


public abstract class ParentBuilder<B extends Rabbit<T>.ParentBuilder<B>>{

    public ParentBuilder(){}

    private String rabbit;

    public B withRabbit(){
        rabbit = "Rabbit";
        return getThis();
    }

    public Rabbit build(){
       return new Rabbit(this);
    }

    public abstract B getThis();


}

}
```

The child class is as follows:

```
public class RabbitChild<T> extends Rabbit<T>{

public RabbitChild(){}

public RabbitChild(ChildBuilder builder){
    this.babyRabbit = builder.babyRabbit;
}

private String babyRabbit;

public String getBabyRabbit(){
    return babyRabbit;
}

public class ChildBuilder extends Rabbit<T>.ParentBuilder<ChildBuilder>{

    private String babyRabbit;

    public ChildBuilder withBabyRabbit(){
        babyRabbit = "BabyRabbit";
        return this;
    }

    public RabbitChild build(){
        return new RabbitChild(this);
    }

    @Override
    public RabbitChild<T>.ChildBuilder getThis() {
        return this;
    }
}


}
```

Removal of the "T" generic makes the withRabbit return type become ChildBuilder, but I do not know why. Is it possible to do this while retaining the generic type?

Comment: Both parent and child `build` methods returns raw types: `Rabbit` and `RabbitChild`.  Your `Rabbit` constructor takes a raw `ParentBuilder`.

Comment: Apologies to all for the confusing question. I found that the issue was not with the "rabbit" classes, but with the way I was trying to instantiate them.